# Wordpress Database table isn't created

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

could someone please help me figure out why wordpress doesn't create the "wp_locations" table when I activate my plugin.

```
global $wp_locations_version;
$wp_locations_version = "1.1";

define( 'LOCATIONURL', plugins_url().'/wp_locations' );

function locations_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $wp_locations_version;


    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_locations (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    location VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lattitude INT,
    longitude INT,
    description MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
    person VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    personimg VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    phone INT,
    sort INT
    );";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);

    add_option("wp_locations_version", $wp_locations_version);
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , 'locations_install' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include at least one KEY field in your SQL.

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table

- You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
- You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the
  definition of your primary key.
- You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and **you must include at least one KEY.**
- You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection to the database in your code. Add a function like this one:

```
        function MySQLConnect( ) {
          $MySQLink = mysql_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD ) ;// These parameters are defined in 'wp-config.php'
          if ( !$MySQLink ) :
            return FALSE ;
          else :
            return $MySQLink ;
          endif ;
        }
```

Then, in function **locations_install()**, add the following lines at the beginning to make the connection:

```
        $Link = MySQLConnect( ) ;
        if ( !$Link ) return FALSE ;
        ...
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**:

Stand corrected Sudar.

The way to do it in Wordpress should be using class wpdb, which does not require a new connection. In that case, there is a problem with:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
```

Plugin scripts are called from wp-admin. It should be:

```
require_once('/includes/upgrade.php');
```

Sorry for missleading.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm not sure that this needs to connect to the database, considering that it is a wordpress plugin and it should already have access to it.

Comment: Yes, you have to make a new connection.

Comment: The OP said it is WordPress. In WordPress you don't have to open your own connection. It will be available in the global $wpdb variable.